# Which Open JDK should I download for CordApp environment?

Tags: java, corda

I am trying to create CordApp environment and I have full Java 14 packages, Git (with recent version), IntelliJ IDEA and I downloaded one of the most recent versions. Which Open JDK should I download? Red hat's Open JDK or Zulu's Open JDK?

Note: I have macOS High Sierra downloaded on my computer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster should be able to find the answer at the CordApp site.

Answer (score 1):

You should be running Java 8, as Java 14 is not supported. See:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/getting-set-up.html

Comment: It says at lest Java 8

Comment: No it doesn't. "Corda supports only Java 8."

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Oracle JDK over Open JDK, for instance Open JDK doesn't have the JavaFX package (which has the [Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) class) and you'd have to install it separately, while Oracle JDK has all the required packages.

See [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/getting-set-up.html#installing-the-java-8-jdk) the JDK's that are supported by Corda.

Comment: I have Oracle's JDK at the latest version

Comment: @AtaTekeli did you read the link that I shared in my answer? It says Java 8, not the latest version.