# CorDapp environment

Tags: corda

I have Java 14 (including JVM, JRE and JDK), have a really late version of Git and the latest versions of intelliJIDEA, Kotlin and Gradle. Should I do anything to completely set the environment up? Can all the above versions interfere with my development environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Open JDK should I download for CordApp environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340631/which-open-jdk-should-i-download-for-cordapp-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Java 14 is not supported in Corda currently. You would need Java 8.

Refer here for the complete list of prerequisites for cordapp development:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/getting-set-up.html